# How to get Bootstrap to keep central column centred at all sizes when the two side columns must disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

This is probably a newbie question but I have tried all kinds of variations of column specs and have failed to get the page to work properly on all viewports. The problem in a nutshell is to keep the centre of three columns centred when viewed in a sm viewport when the left and right columns have to disappear.

My code looks like this:

```html
    <div class="container">       
        <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
         <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="padding-top:125px;"> <!-- 190px;> -->
                <i id="prev" class='fa fa-angle-left prevNext'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="owlCarousel" class="owl-carousel">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-left hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="padding-top:125px;">
                <i id="next" class='fa fa-angle-right prevNext'></i>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <img id="savePlace" src="/assets/img/icon_paperclip_sm.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

At md and lg sizes there are three columns: left column has a 'previous' button to show the previous image, the middle column is an image slider called owl carousel, the right column is the 'next' button. At sm and xs sizes the left and right columns are to disappear (because there is no room for the prev and next buttons). The page looks as it should in md and lg sizes and at xs. But on some viewports at the sm size the image slider is no longer centered and goes to the left edge.

How can I keep the image slider in the centre column centred on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

I had a brain fart on OP's question. Since it is happening when the viewport is getting smaller you can use media queries on a class to only take effect when it hits the @small query defined in Bootstrap.

### EDIT

Updated code to reflect my comment.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="background-color:green">
        <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" style="background-color:red">
        <p>Center Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="background-color:green">
        <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap hides the side columns automatically (no javascript) when you use classes like hidden-sm. My problem is how to make the remaining central column centred rather than full width.

Comment: `col-md-6` is going to take up the entire width of a small screen as you haven't defined a `col-sm-X` for a smaller screen. Even so to center it you need to apply a class that only works when they're on a small screen.

Comment: So then..
`col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3` to your center element.

Comment: Wow I so should have thought of that! I will try it out now.

Comment: Shame, adding that screws up the layout at md and lg. Can't see why it should. It pushes the three columns to the right causing the right column to wrap around. It seems to add a 3 col offset even when in md viewer.

Comment: You are a star! Works a treat (I had to modify the xs to get it to stretch the full width as before). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="background-color:green">
      <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="background-color:red">
      <p>Center Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" style="background-color:blue">
      <p>Center Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="background-color:green">
      <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only issue with the offsets is they need to be applied only to a column that is visible at smaller resolutions. Notice in the above example there are 4 columns, one that is visible on `md` and `lg` and one that is hidden on `md` and `lg`. I applied the offset to the duplicate column as they would interfere with the larger views. Here is a bootply to show what I'm talking about: *(Press the purple desktop to switch to render mode and try resizing the screen)*

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/10G0MuBayD)

Comment: Thanks for that but I am not sure how that applied to my 3 column problem. I don't see how I can have the slider carousel in both of the center columns?